# Generate only modified tables classes - Subsonic

Tags: subsonic

Is there a way to generate classes only tables those got changed (column added, column modified, column deleted etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Not really, but there's usually no reason to worry about that. If you have custom code that you don't want overwritten you can put it in a partial class. Was that the issue?

Comment: Thanks, and nope that is not the issue. Actually I have different workspaces for different bugs so I may need to add a column to one of the work spaces', so what I do is I target a folder separate from my workspaces where subsonic creates classes and then I copy the changed classes and paste them to the workspace I need to. So I just wanted if there is any way subsonic generate only changed classes so that I can just copy and paste them.